# Tanabe-Sugano diagram x-axis question

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-field-theory

While reading up on Tanabe-Sugano diagrams I noticed that many diagrams spread over the internet that all seem to come from this Wikipedia article: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabe–Sugano_diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabe%E2%80%93Sugano_diagram). Those graphs are all derived from this data: http://wwwchem.uwimona.edu.jm/courses/Tanabe-Sugano/TSspread.html

When I myself create the same graph from the same raw data the x-axis is not the same in regards to scale. My question is, since the creator of the Wikipedia graph left no further documentation, what step am I missing?

[image: d8 graph comparison of wiki version and raw data version]

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64486/102629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step that was missing was basically just human error in the creating of the graph (wrong column for x) on top of a 10Dq/B to Dq/B conversion. The Wikipedia graph was correct and the raw data was correct, the creator of the graph on the right (me) made a mistake. My bad.

Comment: I'm still a bit skeptical. To me, your plots make more sense; at least they are coherent with what one typically finds in literature (e.g. [Atkins' *Inorganic Chemistry*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVV4N.png)).

Comment: The raw data used 10Dq/B while the wikipedia one used Dq/B. 10Dq/B is more in line with the literature you linked to. That bit is down to a factor 10 difference, and is more personal preference from what I understand. Compare that with the faulty graph that is off by a factor 17 instead and then my error is easier to see.