# Relative energies of singlet and triplet states in Jablonski diagrams

Tags: electronic-configuration, photochemistry

In a Jablonski diagram, we have singlet and triplet excited states where spin is conserved or changed, respectively. My book says any singlet excited state is found to have higher energy than the corresponding triplet state from the same electron configuration. Why is that?

Comment: [What is the physical basis for Hund's first rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58625/what-is-the-physical-basis-for-hunds-first-rule)

Comment: It is true experimentally that the triplet state arising from the same configuration as the singlet is of lower energy, the answer to this question gives some explanations https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58625/what-is-the-physical-basis-for-hunds-first-rule/58654#58654